# Is it fine to typecast from one implementation type to another while using an object?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I've a simple code base with few 'weapon' concrete classes which implements different contracts in order to be used by its clients.

My contracts:

```
public interface IWeaponPrimaryAttack
{
    void DoAttack();
}
public interface IWeaponSecondaryAttack
{
    void DoSecondaryAttack();
}
public interface IReloadable
{
    void Reload();
}
```

Concrete implementation or the actual weapons:

```
public class Katana : IWeaponPrimaryAttack, IWeaponSecondaryAttack
{
    public void DoAttack(){Console.WriteLine ("Swing");}
    public void DoSecondaryAttack() {Console.WriteLine ("Stab");}
}
public class ShotGun : IWeaponPrimaryAttack, IReloadable
{
    public void DoAttack(){Console.WriteLine ("Swing");}
    public void Reload() {//reload it}
}
```

Clients that uses these concrete classes:

```
public class PrimaryAttack
{
    private IWeaponPrimaryAttack _attack;
    public PrimaryAttack(IWeaponPrimaryAttack attack)
    {
        _attack = attack;
    }
    public void DoAttack()
    {
        _attack.DoAttack();
    }
}
public class SecondaryAttack
{
    private IWeaponSecondaryAttack _attack;
    public SecondaryAttack(IWeaponSecondaryAttack attack)
    {
        _attack = attack;
    }
    public void DoSecondaryAttack()
    {
        _attack.DoSecondaryAttack();
    }
}
public class WeaponReload
{
    private IReloadable _reloader;
    public WeaponReload(IReloadable reloader)
    {
        _reloader = reloader;
    }
    public void Reload()
    {
        _reloader.Reload();
    }
}
```

New of course the instantiation of concrete class only be known when the user selects one among many weapons(one among ShotGun, Katana, etc).

Let say the use has selected ShotGun as the weapon, based on the selection it might go like this:

```
IWeaponPrimaryAttack weapon = new ShotGun(); // get it from a factory
PrimaryAttack primaryAttack = new PrimaryAttack(weapon);
primaryAttack.DoAttack();
```

Now for the `WeaponReload`  have to do a typecast here in order to use it.

```
WeaponReload reloader = new WeaponReload ((IReloadable)weapon);
reloader.Reload();
```

I have questions around it,

- Should I really have to end up typecasting eventually?
- Or there is a better way to handle this object creation part.
- Or there is entirely a better design that I can come up with which
  does not necessarily ends up in casting.
- Or casting it like this is totally fine.

Comment: I think, it's better to ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: However, based on your current code, every weapon should provide a list of supported actions, like reload or secondary attack, then you can build your logic around this. It's also not fully clear, why do you need separate interfaces/classes fro primary and secondary attacks

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Having separate interfaces for primary and secondary action is due to `ShotGun`(or any other gun does not have a secondary attack) so I do not have to implement it. But for  `Katana` it can have 2 actions one is swing and other is stab (just controlled by 2 different keys)

Comment: Even if you decide that typecasting is fine better still check that your weapon is `IReloadable`

Comment: Well, IMHO, that's a candidate for strategy pattern

Answer (score 2):

Not so sure why you need all these extra delegating wrappers? Anyhow, there's a few things at play here.

## Maximizing composition

You've used a concrete type per weapon type here, but you could also put more emphasis on composition and have a single all-encompassing `Weapon` class that delegates all it's inner workings to [strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

e.g.

Rather than `Weapon shotgun = new Shotgun();` you could have `Weapon shotgun = Weapons.shotgun()` where the factory method may look like:

```
return new Weapon.Builder()
    .withPrimaryAttack(...)
    .withoutSecondaryAttack()
    .withSlowReload().build();
```

Maximizing composition makes the design very flexible and could allow you to introduce new weapon types dynamically if needed or even change certain aspects of a weapon at runtime (e.g. shotgun now fires knifes b/c of a picked-up powerup).

## Following the [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)

In the composition-based approach described above, you may notice that the `Weapon`'s interface will become bloated with all sort of things weapons can do. Clients depending on the `Weapon` class will indirectly depend on all the various implicit interface methods they may never call.

In order to reduce clients coupling you could very well make sure that `Weapon` features are segregated into many interfaces such as `IReloadable`, etc. The `Weapon` class would implement them all, but client code interested in only a subset of weapon features could still depend on these interfaces rather than `Weapon`.

e.g.

```
reload(weapon);

void reload(IReloadable reloadable) {
    if (stamina < ...) throw ...;

    reloadable.reload();
}
```

## **ISP & feature-detection**

Considering your original design, I don't think there's anything fundamentally wrong with using `instanceof` as a feature detection mechanism.

Using `instanceof` to match concrete types is certainly wrong, but matching interfaces is most likely fine.

```
weapon instanceof Shotgun //bad
weapon instanceof IReloadable //ok
```

Note that you should always check with `instanceof` before casting. Also note that you need to think of an approach to make weapon implementers know the set of potential weapon-feature interfaces they could implement.